# Appropriate to make this class static?

Tags: php, class, static

I've got a small input helper class.

I read a lot that static classes are not the best to use. But I still haven't grasp why I shouldn't use static classes. I'm not that advanced yet, so maybe I will figure it out later on.

The reason I made it static is that it's not an object that's unique every time it's being called in my script.

**Is it a good thing that I made the class static?**

```
class Input {
    public static function exists($type = 'post') {
        switch($type) {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
            break;
            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    public static function get($input, $source = 'post') {
        if($source == 'post' && isset($_POST[$input])) {
            return $_POST[$input];
        } else if($source == 'get' && isset($_GET[$input])) {
            return $_GET[$input];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated code

```
class Input {
    private $_get,
            $_post;

    public function __construct($get, $post) {
        $this->_get  = $get;
        $this->_post = $post;
    }

    public function exists($type = 'POST') {
        switch($type) {
            case 'POST':
                return (!empty($this->_post)) ? true : false;
            break;
            case 'GET':
                return (!empty($this->_get)) ? true : false;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    public function get($input, $source = 'POST') {
        if($source == 'POST' && isset($this->_post[$input])) {
            return $this->_post[$input];
        } elseif($source == 'GET' && isset($this->_get[$input])) {
            return $this->_get[$input];
        }
        throw new Exception('Undefined index: ' . $input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `isset` and `empty` are not the same thing. Your `exists` function lies. If a value exists, but is empty, like `""` (empty string) your `exists` function will return `false` where it should return `true`.

Comment: +1. Thanks for pointing that out. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have only one of something doesn't mean it has to be static. Especially in regard to Unit tests, static classes are hard to deal with.

Your class `Input` is bound to `$_GET` and `$_POST`. This means you can not use it in Unit tests.

If instead your class looked like this:

```
$input = new Input($_GET, $_POST);
```

ie. you give it the global dependencies, now `Input` *can* be tested because you can mock the values of `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unit testing yet.

Comment: Just see it like this: there is no advantage to using static classes. It can only lead to poor design and bad test-ability.

Comment: Maybe another way of looking at it is like this: if you're fine with using `$_GET["foo"]` then using `Input::get("foo")` is also fine. Your helper _hides_ the `Undefined index` issues which might even be bad. If you change the `return false` in `get` to `throw new Exception("Undefined index: " . $input");` that would be fine. As it is your helper doesn't really add anything.

Comment: I have edited my code. Does that look better? Made it instantiatable, and added a throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a static class, you could do something like this :

```
class Input {

    private $array;

    function __construct($array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function exists() {
        return isset($this->array);
    }

    public function get($input) {
        if($this->exists() && isset($this->array[$input])) {
            return $this->array[$input];
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$get = new Input($_GET);
$value = $get->get('key');

$post = new Input($_POST);
$value = $post->get('key');
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the dependency on global variables, it might even make it worse. Now if you did `$get = new Input($_GET); $post = new Input($_POST);` that would be fine.

Comment: Thank for the comment, I updated the code accordingly